# accountmenu for D7?

Tags: users

In Drupal 6, I've been using the `accountmenu` module to get a nice couple of links that change dynamically between `[Log in/Create account]` and `[My account][Log out]` according to whether or not the user's logged in.

It doesn't look like this module's been ported to D7 yet though, can anyone recommend an alternative?  Or perhaps there are nicer ways to solve this now than in D6?

The module really isn't very large, the D7 porting effort probably would be pretty easy, but I'm new to D7 and I'd probably not do a very good job with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem easily for all my D7 installs by simply having two account menus - one with links for anonymous users such as 'login, create account' and the other with menu items to manage the account and logout.

If you set the roles so that 'anonymous' users only see the anonymous menu block, and set the authenticated for the authenticated menu block, then these will switch out seamlessly. Best of all, no custom code or extra modules required!